# href="?logout=true"> which script is executed?

Tags: php

My php application header is having the below href in the header for logout.
I am not understanding which logout php file it is executing here. Is it executing `present_page.php?logout=true`. May I also know ho how this is executed.
href="?logout=true">

```
<div>
    <a class="linkBlack" href="index.php">Home</a> |
    <a class="linkBlack" href="pre_sub_v2.php">ACE</a> |
    <a class="linkBlack" href="profile.php">My Profile</a> |
    <a class="linkBlack" href="faq_list.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a> |    
    <a class="linkBlack" href="comm.php">Communications Dashboard</a> |
    <a class="linkBlack" href="?logout=true">Logout</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about. Show as your code.

Comment: @AmithReddy Yes it will likely load your current page but with `$_GET['logout']` set to true. What happens when you actually click on it?

Comment: The actual page you're on

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the path, the current path is used and the querystring "?logout=true" is concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

if you currently in "present_page.php" , then definitely it will be as follows;

present_page.php?logout=true